# Canon T3i/600D - save images directly to an external hard drive

Tags: storage, canon-600d

Is there a way to connect an external hard disk directly to a Canon T3i/600D in order to copy photos directly from the card to the disk, without using a computer.

Answer (score 2):

There are hard-drive enclosures and even DVD burners which run independently from a computer and have memory card slots to perform such copies.

Several manufacturers make such drives casings: [Hyperdrive](http://www.hypershop.com/HyperDrive-COLORSPACE-UDMA-s/64.htm), [Wolverine](http://secure.mm5server.com/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=WD&Category_Code=FlashPac) and Epson (Can't find the link) are the most popular.

All you do is insert the memory card into the device and with a few button presses, its contents get copied into the disk.

Comment: Actually, there is simply a computer inside the housing. Embedded computers with Ethernet and WiFi are easy to find.

So far, no camera can directly drive an external hard disk (unless its there, hidden) but Samsung has announced a compact camera with Android, so tomorrow, it may be different.

Comment: @PatFarrell FYI: Nikon has a camera with Android too, the [Coolpix S800c](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/nikon/s800c) with WiFi.